# Get user's skype status with skype online connector on powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business

I'm working on a little script that outputs the current Skype for Business Status of a user.

> Available, Busy, Do Not Disturb. etc.

I already experimented a bit and can output a lot of information. The Script works fine but I can't find a status entry.

This is my code so far:

```
$userCredential = Get-Credential
$sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $userCredential

Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector
Import-PSSession $sfbSession #connection opens

Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity "buttercup@sup.onmicrosoft.com"

$currentSession = Get-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session $currentSession #connection closes
```

Am I searching on the wrong spot?

If there is any more information I should provide please ask, I hope we can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone wondering, I solved this problem.
Instead of using the `Skype Online Connector`, I use the [`Skype Lync 2013 SDK`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824).

With this simple code, I can achieve what I wanted.

```
$client = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()
$contact = $client.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("spiderman@marvel.com")
$availabilityId = $contact.GetContactInformation("Availability")
$activity = $contact.GetContactInformation("Activity")
Write-Output ([Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactAvailability]$availabilityId)
```

Note that this in this example, there is no need to enter any credentials, because `GetClient()` already gets the credentials of your open Skype for Business Service.

Comment: What format does the skype URI follow?  Btw, I can't imagine they use a hard-coded list of INTs for availability.  I'd check if there is an enum to compare to

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 works with the email of your azure account. (for example "buttercup@sup.onmicrosoft.com")

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thank you, I edited it. And because of that hard-coded table. I took [this](https://rcosic.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/availability-presence-in-lync-client/) as a reference.

Comment: [Link to enum doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/lync-wpf/jj293978%28v%3doffice.15%29).  This allows you to skip the switch entirely: `Write-Output ([Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactAvailability]$availabilityId)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 you are right, that is great! thank you.

Comment: as another note, since this is a .net library and not a powershell module, or cmdlet, I'd suggest using `Add-Type -Path $path` instead of `Import-Module` when adding this dll to your code.